# Addition of numbers using single textbox?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me out in how to get or read two values from single textbox.
i.e when i read the first value it should be stored in string str1 , when operator button is clicked the textbox shld be cleared but must know which operator button was clicked and shld wait to accept second value.The second value shld be stored in str2.
This is like a simple calculator wherein we enter many number in one textbox.
Thank You
Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {
       var value1 = "", value2 = "", result="";
        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value;
            value1 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
            value2 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btnadd').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnadd').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btneql').addEventListener('click', function () {

           result = value1 + value2;

        });
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsfiddle%20calculator)

Comment: sorry i did not get your point. Yaje .... Can u please explain what are you trying to say to me?

Comment: "Fiddle" means use this website https://jsfiddle.net/ to create a self-contained environment with the necessary HTML/JavaScript/CSS to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Jquery

1. By `click()` event get the value of your input `$('.YourInput').val()`
2. Increase your sum
3. Clear your input `$('.YourInput').val("")`

   [see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aa78fj0t/)

   #### Update

Using Javascript:
If the user click on number button: 0-9 the value will be concatenated with the previous value, if the user clicked on `plus` operation the given value in the text field will be memorised till the user gives a new value and click on `equal`
Operation.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx326npr/)

```js
var value1=value2=result=0;
function calc(val) {
    value1= parseInt(document.getElementById(val).value);
    document.getElementById("textBox").value=document.getElementById("textBox").value+value1;
    value1=parseInt(document.getElementById("textBox").value);
}
function DoSumm(){
    document.getElementById("textBox").value="";
    value2=value1;
    value1=0;
}
function FindResult(){
    result=value1+value2;
    alert(result);
    document.getElementById("textBox").value=result;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text"   id="textBox" size="5"/>
    <br/><br/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="button" id="btnone"   value="  1  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btntwo"   value="  2  " OnCLick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnthree" value="  3  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnfour"  value="  4  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnfive"  value="  5  " OnCLick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnsix"   value="  6  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnseven" value="  7  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btneight" value="  8  " OnCLick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnnine"  value="  9  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnzero"  value="  0  " OnClick="calc(this.id)"/>
    <input type="button" id="btneql"  value="  =  " OnClick="FindResult()"/>
    <input type="button" name="plus"  value="  +  " OnClick="DoSumm()"/>
    <br/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please help me out doing this stuff using javascript. And one thing is that there must be buttons from  (0 to 9 ) for input also.

Comment: A completely useless answer.

Comment: why? this do the task: get the sum of all inputs and clear the input text every time the user gives a new value

Comment: still i cannot achieve what i desire. Provide me hint for solution in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the related HTML, otherwise we have to reverse engineer it. Anyhow, perhaps you have something like:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" id="btnone" name="btnone" value="0">
  <br>
  <textarea name="textBox"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="btntwo" name="btntwo" value="0">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="btnadd" name="btnadd" value="Add">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="btneql" name="btneql" value="Equal">
  <br>
  <input type="text" readonly name="result">
</form>
```

In your function you have:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var value1 = "", value2 = "", result="";
```

Variables don't have a type in javascript, so there's no point in initialising them to a value unless you intend to actually use it, so:

```
  var value1, value2, result;
```

Then there is:

```
  document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value;
    value1 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
  });
```

All that code for so little work! If you add a listener using *addEventListener*, then the element will be *this* within the function. Also, you can use the names of form controls to reference them as named properties of the form, so:

```
  var textBox = this.form.textBox;
  textBox.value = textBox.value + this.value;
```

You don't say what the value of *btnone* is (I've assumed it's zero), but in any case it will be a string, as will the value of the text box. So you need to convert them to Numbers, otherwise `+` will do concatenation not addition. The easy way is to use the unary + operator, so:

```
  textBox.value = +textBox.value + +this.value;
```

Then you do:

```
  value1 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
```

So *value1* is a string again, so do it in the other order:

```
  value1 = +textBox.value + +this.value;
  textBox.value = value1;
```

And keep going… The code looks quite turgid and I don't really know if the following does what you're trying to do (particularly the listener on the *btnadd* element), at least it "works":

```
window.onload = function () {
  var value1 = "", value2 = "", result="";

  document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var textBox = this.form.textBox;
    value1 = +textBox.value + +this.value;
    textBox.value = value1;
  });

  document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var textBox = this.form.textBox;
    value2 = +textBox.value + +this.value;
    textBox.value = value2;
  });

  document.getElementById('btnadd').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var textBox = this.form.textBox;
    textBox.value = value1 + value2;
  });

  document.getElementById('btneql').addEventListener('click', function () {
    result = value1 + value2;
    this.form.result.value = result;
  });
};
```